$G(n,1/2)$ has a bipartite subgraph with at least $n^2/8+Cn^{3/2}$ edges
I want to show that with probability converging to $1$, $G(n,1/2)$ has a bipartite subgraph with at least $n^2/8+Cn^{3/2}$ edges for some positive constant $C$. The hint for this is to use a greedy algorithm where we sequentially append a vertex to maximize the number of edge crossings. I am not sure how to compute the probabilities or expected values with this algorithm. Anyone have suggestions or a solution?
This problem is kind of like a converse to this problem.

You can check Babai, László, Miklós Simonovits, and Joel Spencer. "Extremal subgraphs of random graphs." Journal of Graph Theory 14.5 (1990): 599-622.
(From page 616)

Link: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jgt.3190140511

Try using a simpler algorithm. Maintain partition $U_i,V_i$ and introduce vertices 2 at a time $a_i,b_i$ for $i=1,\ldots, \lfloor n/2\rfloor$. Initialize $U_0=V_0=\emptyset$, and at each step $i$, define $(U_i,V_i)$ to be $(U_{i-1}\cup\{a_i\},V_{i-1}\cup\{b_i\})$ or $(U_{i-1}\cup\{b_i\},V_{i-1}\cup\{a_i\})$, whichever has more cross-edges. Let $X_i$ be the number of cross-edges added at this step, and then $X=\sum_iX_i$ is the final size of the partition. Now observe that at each step $i$, $X_i$ is distributed according to the maximum of two independent binomial $\text{Bin}(2i-2,1/2)$ distributions.
You could use this to show $\mathbb E[X]=n^2/8+\Theta(n^{3/2})$, and then use Azuma's inequality to get concentration on an interval of size $O(n\log n)$. This would probably be tedious; I wonder if there is a simpler proof.
